# AJAX validation not working with struts2 Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2

I am writing a web application with struts2 + Jquery plugin.
I am using AJAX form submission with sj:submit tag from jquery plugin.
I am facing an issue while validating the form (AJAX) with "validate= true" tag in sj:submit.
Following is the sj:submit tag:

```
<sj:submit value="ADDUSERNOW" onBeforeTopics="before" onSuccessTopics="success" 
    onErrorTopics="errorState" onCompleteTopics="complete" targets="userMgmntDiv" validate="true"/>
```

My html head section also contains references to two js files required for validation as below.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/struts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/struts/xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Validation xml is given below which is named as ActionClass-validation.xml and is placed in the same package as that of a class on which validation is invoked:

```
        <validators>
            <field name="userModel.userName">
                <field-validator type="requiredstring">
                    <message>UserName Is Required</message>
                </field-validator>
            </field>
        </validators>
```

After form is submitted , no validation is triggered , and execution proceeds and struts2 action class is called.
Is there anything I am missing here ? I have searched a lot but couldn't find any answer .Please help
struts2-core version : 2.3.4 
struts2-jquery-plugin :3.3.3 
Action configuration looks loke below :

```
<action class="addUserAction" method="addUser">
    <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
    <result>addUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In addition to above,I am using spring + struts2 + hibernate for achieving above task.When I tried the example as shown in struts2-jason wiki page : ,I am getting error as : cannot find action with class named AddUserAction(which is a bean in spring-beans.xml)
It seems that error is thrown when validator inteceptor is invoked.
When I comment out the annotations used for validation on the action class - AddUserAction, this error vanishes and page loads successfully. 
Following are my questions  : 
1)How can I use spring alongwith struts2 convention plugin ? This is because , convention plugin uses its own mechanism for mapping urls and action (using annotations or default behaviour). 
2)Previuosly , I was expecting struts.xml file can be used for url to action mapping , and annotations can be used for validations. (using convention plugin)But this approach doesn't seem to work.(convention plugin + struts.xml doesn't work)

Comment: Do you have any errors in the JavaScript Console? How looks your Action Configuration? Do you have added the jsonValidationWorkflowStack Interceptor? Do you see a XHR request with firebug or similar tool?

Comment: @jogep, I am not getting any error in the java script console .
Action configuration includes the jsonValidationWorkflowStack interceptor. When ajax request is sent to server , XHR request is sent to server (captured with httpfox and firebug too.).
Action configuration is posted in the question. Also , the example shown in the wiki page (and also in the strutrs2-showcase.war )shows annotations which requires struts2-convention plugin. 
Do I need to use convention plugin only (more specifically annotations )? I am using declarative validation instead of annotations.

Answer (score 1):

struts2 `ajax validation` is a client side validation, which provided natively by dojo, here is the doc for [Struts2 Ajax validation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ajax-validation.html). `struts2-jquery plugin` provides this feature using `jsonValidationWorkflowStack`, you can use it like this: [Example](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Validation)

Comment: Of course Struts2 jQuery Plugin is providing a client side validation feature. See http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Validation for details or take a look at the showcase examples.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried. It's work very well. But if your form has an input file for upload, the ajax validation don't work.